# SQL: how to retrieve data in month and year range

Tags: sql-server, database

I have query in which I want the result in month and year range like
data should be in between January/2010 and March/2012..

Can anybody help me.. I have done like...:

```
(DATENAME(MM, c.startdate) >= 'January' and DATEPART(YEAR, c.startdate) >= 2010) and
(DATENAME(MM, c.startdate) <= 'January' and DATEPART(YEAR, c.startdate) <= 2012)
```

bue still not getting porper result

Thnaks in advance

Comment: Which is your database? MS SQL Server ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use:

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE c.startDate >= '20100101' AND c.startDate < '20120401'
```

That just selects all the rows with a `startDate` between Jan 1, 2010, and before Apr 1, 2012

Comment: but i need to give in month and year range only... m using that query for generating reports further in SSRS 2008..

Comment: Even if you want month and year only you can still use this method.
If user asks for Jan 2010 to Mar 2012 you need all records with date greater than or equal to 1st Jan 2012 AND less than 1st Apr 2012. Right?. I think that is the logic @marc_s have implemented here. Please think about it.

Comment: Also note that, using 1st April here instead of trying to findout which is the last day of March is both simple and possibly faster solution. So I will put a +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select
    ...
Where Dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, c.startdate),0) between '2012-01-01' and '2012-04-01'
```

**EDIT:**
I'm now assuming that your month and date are the input that you are using.

```
Declare @month1 varchar(20), @year1 int
  ,@month2 varchar(20), @year2 int
  ,@realmonth1 int, @realmonth2 int
  ,@first int, @input1 datetime, @input2 datetime
Set @month1 = 'January'
Set @year1 = 2010
Set @month2 = 'January'
Set @year2 = 2012
Set @realmonth1 = Case when @month1 = 'January' then '01' when @month1 = 'February' then '02' when @month1 = 'March' then '03' when @month1 = 'April' then '04' when @month1 = 'May' then '05' when @month1 = 'June' then '06' when @month1 = 'July' then '07' when @month1 = 'August' then '08' when @month1 = 'Sepetember' then '09' when @month1 = 'October' then '10' when @month1 = 'November' then '11' when @month1 = 'December' then '12' end
Set @realmonth2 = Case when @month2 = 'January' then '01' when @month2 = 'February' then '02' when @month2 = 'March' then '03' when @month2 = 'April' then '04' when @month2 = 'May' then '05' when @month2 = 'June' then '06' when @month2 = 'July' then '07' when @month2 = 'August' then '08' when @month2 = 'Sepetember' then '09' when @month2 = 'October' then '10' when @month2 = 'November' then '11' when @month2 = 'December' then '12' end
Set @first = 1
Set @input1 = convert(datetime,(convert(nvarchar(4), @year1) + '-' + convert(nvarchar(2), @realmonth1) + '-' + convert(nvarchar(2), @first)))
Set @input2 = convert(datetime,(convert(nvarchar(4), @year2) + '-' + convert(nvarchar(2), @realmonth2) + '-' + convert(nvarchar(2), @first)))

Select
    ...
Where startdate between @input1 and @input2
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a82d5/1) showing that it works, also tested in MS SQL Server 2005

Comment: but i need to give in month and year range only... m using that query for generating reports further in SSRS 2008..

Comment: @Manisha is the month and year your input from the end user?

Comment: @Manisha You seem to be posting same reply for all answers without trying to understand the answer. That is not so nice.

Answer (score 0):

try using a statement containing `month(c.startdate) >= 1`  and `year(c.startdate) >= 2010`. That makes it easier for you

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say, but you can really define a range using what i posted above.